# Managed identity and Sites.Selected permission for SharePoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to understand how to use managed identity to connect to SharePoint. Everywhere I can read that I should create a new managed identity in the portal (I did that) and then somehow assing Sites.Selected permission... But I can assign such permission only to App registrations. And I do not have an app registration - I have this managed identity. In the portal I can see only something like that:[image]

So I cannot add there any permissions??? Then how I am suppose to use this managed identity and assign it the correct permission? I have tries with the script:

```
Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppId <my managed identity principal id> -DisplayName 'Test' -Site <my site url> -Permissions Write
```

But then after executing

```
Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppId <my managed identity principal id> -Site <my site url>
```

I get in response:

```
Id    : aTowaS50fG1zLnNwLnV4dHwzYmVhYTUyYS1iNzgxLTRjNDQtYTNkYy0wMmJhNWYzMjVhZWNAZjI1NDkzYWUtMWM5OC00MWQ3LThhMzMtMGJlNzVmNWZlNjAz
Roles :
Apps  : {Test, 3beca52a-b781-4c44-a3dc-02ba5f325aec}
```

So looks like roles are not set or what?
Still, I have tried to get the access token (running in azure function deployed to azure with assigned this managed identity I am trying to set up):

```
var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
await credential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext("<url to site>/.default"));
```

But I receive only 400 bad request...

Or maybe it is not possible to use managed identities in this way and I am actually trying to do something completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one managed identity named **`MI-TEST`** same as you like below:

[image]

When I checked **permissions** of this in Enterprise application, I got same screen as below:

[image]

To add **`Sites.Selected`** SharePoint permission to above enterprise application, you can make use of Azure AD PowerShell module.

Make sure to have proper role while connecting to Azure AD. In my case, I connected with **Global Administrator** credentials like below:

```
Connect-AzureAD
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now I ran below PowerShell script to add **`Sites.Selected`** SharePoint permission for managed identity and got **response** like below:

```
$msi = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "MI-TEST"
$sharepoint = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'"
$role = $sharepoint.AppRoles | where Value -Like "Sites.Selected" | Select-Object -First 1

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment `
             -Id $role.Id `
             -ObjectId $msi.ObjectId `
             -PrincipalId $msi.ObjectId `
             -ResourceId $sharepoint.ObjectId
```

**Response:**
[image]

When I checked the same in Portal under Enterprise application, **`Sites.Selected`** permission added successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I cannot test this now but looks promising!